# Is there a program that uses static analysis to look for bugs in actionscript code?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, static-analysis

Is thre any program which uses static analysis to look for bugs in actionscript code?

Comment: Are you going to go through every language with this question?  You even copy/pasted the same misspelling from your last question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598882/is-thre-any-program-which-uses-static-analysis-to-look-for-bugs-in-scala-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FlexPMD](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD) is probably the only thing resembling this. You can tune/train it to fit your needs.